# Why does git keep deleting my folder?

Tags: git

I have a folder in my repository called 'activity'. It keeps getting strangely deleted from the repository, and isn't seen as an untracked file.

In github, it is rendered as a folder with a green arrow, and the text '→ f32111b' next to it. This has happened several times now, and only with this one folder.

I've already checked .gitignore. Is there another reason why a folder called 'activity' would be trouble in git?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about when it gets deleted (i.e., what command are you performing, etc)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not a directory, that's a submodule. Or at least GitHub seems to think so.

What does your `.gitmodules` file look like? Did you maybe forget to run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`?

Submodules can be a little bit tricky, especially when you convert from a directory to a submodule or back.

Comment: This was my problem. I had never before used git submodule, so didn't know to use it for this.

Comment: Can you link to some supplemental info here? I've seen some "permalinked" folders in other people's repos...mine won't hyperlink to the repo I cloned. For the lazy: [No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'your/path'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)

Answer (score 5):

Is the directory empty?

Git doesn't track empty dirs.

The hack trick is to touch an empty file in there if you really need to keep the directory kicking around.

Comment: Most common used file name for this is empty `.gitignore` file (or `.gitkeep` file).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer madlep gave (git doesn't tracks empty directories):

http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#CanIaddemptydirectories.3F:

> That is, directories never have to be
>   added to the repository, and are not
>   tracked on their own.